# Express.js res.render and res.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have some problem with express.js. I want to render my template on first request, and then get some data from routs. My routing look like:

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.render('index.jade');
 next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){  
  res.json({a:1});
})

app.get('/contacts', function(req, res){  
  res.json({a:1});
})

app.get('/emails', function(req, res){  
  res.json({a:1});
})
```

The problem is that every request i do, set response to html/text by my middleware, and i can't get to other routs. Mb some one know how i can render template only once, and than be able to get to the other routs (i try to do SPA with express and backbone)

Answer (score 2):

**Solutions**
You convert jade to html and place  **index.html** file in the public folder

Enable express static files serve

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

define  and other specific routes returns static files and api like in **(api|css|js)**

```
    app.route('/:url(api|css|js)/*')
       .get(function (req, res) {
          var viewFilePath = '404';
          var statusCode = 404;
          var result = {
            status: statusCode
          };

          res.status(result.status);
          res.render(viewFilePath, function (err) {
            if (err) { return res.json(result, result.status); }
    // 404.jade file
            res.render(viewFilePath);
          });
        });

      // All other routes should redirect to the index.html
      app.route('/*')
        .get(function(req, res) {
// SPA index  file
          res.sendfile('/public/index.html');
        });
```

Now you can use

```
app.get('/api/emails', function(req, res){  
  res.json({a:1});
});
app.get('/api/contacts', function(req, res){  
  res.json({a:1});
});
```

Comment: '/api/emails' this routs use this /:url(api|css|js)/* condition in result, mb i doing something wrong?

Comment: `app.route('/:url(api|css|js)/*')` folder code block finds the route. If not available it throw 404. for all other cases `app.route('/*')` it returns index.html file. and this code are appended at the end. all the routes defined before this code.